# Configure Wildfly 10 to block simultaneous repeating servlet calls

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10

Is it possible to configure in the wildfly 10 undertow to block simultaneous repeating servlet calls from one user?

I want to have only the first HTTP call from the application to reach the servlet and the next repeating calls from the same user should be blocked until the first servlet request has been completed. I know this is possible from the java application itself by setting the method as synchronized, but that will block all requests for all the others users and i think its a bad programming practice. Please advice.